# Integrating an apk with another source code for Android Development

Tags: android

I am developing an application which needs to click a picture of barcode and then decode it.
I need to call the barcode scanner app which i have already downloaded and for which i have the barcode scanner apk. I need to call this apk in the source code of my application. Is it possible? How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call a third party application's activity in the following way.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(BarcodeSanner package name);
```

`intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("BarcodeSanner package name","BarcodeSanner activity name"));`

```
startActivity(intent );
```

you can catch exception if the application is not there in you phone

Comment: but i dont have source code for barcode scanner application. I just have barcode scanner apk.

Comment: run barcode scanner and check logcat you will get package details ;)